# Why is this code giving bad file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I am having issue with the following code. It is giving me bad file descriptor error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
        int fd = open("/tmp/test", O_RDONLY);
        long len = 20;
        long word;
        ssize_t ret;
        if(fd == -1)
        {
                perror("open");
                return 1;
        }
        if(len > SSIZE_MAX)
        {
                len = SSIZE_MAX;
        }
        ret = read(fd, &word, len);
        while(len != 0 && ret != 0)
        {
                if(ret == -1)
                {
                        if(errno == EINTR)
                        {
                                continue;
                        }
                        perror("read");
                        break;
                }
                len -= ret;
                word += ret;
                ret = read(fd, &word, len);
        }
        close(fd);
}
```

Upon debugging I have found that after first iteration the value of `fd` is changed to a large number. I do not know how this is happening.

Comment: You read `20` bytes into 1 `long`, which has space for 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: Yes right got it, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
 ret = read(fd, &word, len);
```

causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior),as you're trying to read `20` bytes into a memory designated for `sizeof(long)` which is much less than what is required.

One correct way of writing this would be

```
ret = read(fd, &word, sizeof(word));
```

Comment: Thanks Sourav, you are a hero.

Comment: And sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer. I am a newbie.

Comment: You're welcome. @ahmedrajput If it helped to solve your problem you can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062). Don't bother about upvotes, anyway.